# How to mark rectangle shape over the image cv2

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

```
customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_menu, text='Mark Image',
               command=self.draw_action).grid(
        row=3,
        column=0,
        columnspan=2,
        padx=5,
        pady=5,
        sticky='sw',
        )
def draw_action(self):
    self.color_code = ((255, 0, 0), '#ff0000')
    self.refresh_side_frame()
    self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress>', self.start_draw)
    self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw)
    self.draw_color_button = ttk.Button(self.side_frame,
            text='Pick A Color', command=self.choose_color)
    self.draw_color_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5,
                                sticky='sw')

def choose_color(self):
    self.color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title='Choose color')

def prev_action(self):
    self.color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title='Choose color')    

def next_action(self):
    self.color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title='Choose color')  

def start_draw(self, event):
    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y
    self.draw_ids = []

def draw(self, event):
    # print(self.draw_ids)
    self.draw_ids.append(self.canvas.create_line(
        self.x,
        self.y,
        event.x,
        event.y,
        width=2,
        fill=self.color_code[-1],
        capstyle=ROUND,
        joinstyle=ROUND,
        smooth=True,
        ))

    cv2.rectangle(
        self.filtered_image,
        (int(self.x * self.ratio), int(self.y * self.ratio)),
        (int(event.x * self.ratio), int(event.y * self.ratio)),
        (0, 255, 0),
        thickness=int(self.ratio * 2),
        lineType=8,
        )

    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y
```

When click button to start draw a line but I want to draw rectangle on this. If I'm changing `cv2.rectangle` it always show line draw I don't know why. I want rectangle shape over the image it like mark important section and save this marked file.

Comment: `cv2.rectangle(image, start_point, end_point, color, thickness)`  You tried this? Then show your attempt at this. Did you get an error?

Comment: i tried this but not working

Comment: Then show this try. Also we cant see where you call this function.

Comment: I'm edited the code please check and tell me

Comment: So when you run the rectangle function it draws a line?

Comment: yes when i click draw_action button it start draw a line but i want rectangle shape

Comment: Have you tried debugging? perhaps the width of your rectangle is zero hence why you get a line?

Comment: This is store in array if i'm draw D:/books\637.jpg
[]
[3]
[3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

Comment: What is that meant to represent?

Comment: array in  `def start_draw(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y
        self.draw_ids = []`

Comment: please prepare a [mre]. this code, as is, is not debuggable. and perhaps review [ask]. you should work on your problem a little. learn how to debug your code. it's an indispensable skill.

Comment: Where do you want the rectangle be drawn on? `self.canvas` or `self.filtered_image` (what is it? An image loaded by `cv2` module?)? There are many unknown information in your question.

Comment: I want self.filtered_image over the image